# Problem with success/redirect URL for ModelForm form_valid() function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am having a bit of difficulty with overriding the `form_valid()` method of a `CreateView`.

I have a `ModelForm` where users can register a new patient. The form is handled by a `CreateView`. I have overridden the `form_valid()` method of the view as I first need to assing the user to the patient and then assess whether the details of the patient (i.e. data in the form) meet certain criteria. If the criteria are not met, the patient/form is not saved and the user gets an error message. If they are eligible the patient/form is saved and the user gets a success message.
This functionality of the form/view is working - in the test code below I have a boolean 'is_eligible' which I will substitute out for the proper criteria later. When `is_eligible == True` the model saves and I get a success message, when it `== False` it does not save and I get the `error` message.

My problem is handling the success url and redirect if the patient isn't eligible. I would like it to go back to a 'dashboard' that I have setup, but each time I do I get a

```
DisallowedRedirect at /dashboard/patients/register
Unsafe redirect URL with protocol 'accounts'
```

If anyone can provide insight/suggestions about how to get this work, would be greatly appreciated.

My current code:

forms.py

```
class PatientRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'is_eligible']
```

views.py

```
class PatientRegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Patient
    form_class = PatientRegisterForm
    template_name = 'patients/register.html'
    success_url = 'accounts:dashboard'

    def patient_eligible(self, test):
        if not test.is_eligible:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.provider = self.request.user
        test = form.save(commit=False)
        if self.patient_eligible(test):
            messages.success(self.request, 'Patient registered successfully!')
            test.save()
            return super().form_valid(form) # fails here if eligible
        else:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Patient not registered')
            return redirect(self.request, 'accounts:dashboard') # fails here if not eligible
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't think you need to pass self.request as first parameter of redirect.
From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) redirect should be like this

```
redirect(to, permanent=False, *args, **kwargs)
```

But the real problem that's causing your error is that you are not reversing the url. What you need to do is:

```
from django.shorcts import reverse_lazy
..
success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:dashboard')
..
return redirect(reverse('accounts:dashboard'))
```

Comment: This seems to be causing a circular import error when I define `success_url = reverse('accounts:dashboard')`. The dev server crashed and the last line states `The included URLconf 'project.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

Comment: ok, i have the fix for that too, use lazy. See updated answer